# What is the recommended MVC design pattern for adding non-existent foreign key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys

You are building an MVC5 EF6 application where the user will add musical albums. A musical album has artist, record label, and category foreign keys which are each represented my their own respective models. On the create album page, the user will select through a drop downs the record label, category and artist. What happens if that artist or record label hasn't been entered yet?

Does the user have to go to the artist or record label view to add it first, then go back to the album page to create the album? Is there a better way to optimize the user process flow?

I had considered using a UI accordion that would be in the album view which would have panels for the album, artist, record label and category models. The artist, record label and category panels would start collapsed. If the user selects "Other" in the drop down for the artist, record label, category , the respective  panel would expand and give the user the opportunity to enter the necessary fields to create the record label on the fly. Is this a bad idea? Are there other options I haven't considered that make the process easy for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really only two options here:

1. Let the input form allow a new entry for Record Label, etc. This opens up the possibility of course of duplicate entries (spelling, abbreviation, etc.)
2. Create another form(s) where you manage those foreign keys, allowing someone to add a new label, artist, etc. The same possibility of duplication exists, however you might be able to introduce some fuzzy logic to search for similar names when an entry is added.

Either of these methods could also incorporate moderation, forcing new entries to be vetted by you or by some other entity, but of course that takes time. The biggest factor for me in making that decision would be whether or not the users of the system could be trusted to make intelligent decisions. (ie find an existing name and use that rather than just keep duplicating)

As far as the design, that's highly preferential and doesn't really have a correct answer. The best solution there is to make a mock up and have someone unfamiliar with the project use the site and get their feedback, and make changes accordingly.